# CQRS+ES: irrelevant Command/Event for Aggregate but important for Projection

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

I have **Application** *aggregate*, it can handle *commands* like **Register**, **Install**, **Uninstall**, **Hide**, **Show**, **ChangeOwner**, **Publish**, **CancelPublication**... there is around 20 *commands* in **Application** *aggregate*. Each *command* checks invariants of **Application** for instance **Application** can be:

- **Published** when name, description and other details are valid,
- **Hidden** only when is **Published**,
- **Installed** not by owner and after when it is **Published**,
- **PublicationCanceled** when there are no installations...

**Application** generates respective *events* when *commands* are valid. *Events* are handled by *projections* and *process managers*.

I have **Application** and **Statistics** *projection* - they handle events from **Application** *aggregate*, both *projections* are 100% based on *events*, so that *projections* can be totally deleted and rebuild from scratch. **Application** and **Statistics** *projections* are requested by users through *http:get endpoint*

**Problem**:

Now I have a request from business analytics to track when **Application** is **Opened** by potential customer. By **Opening** they understand that potential customer see **Application** *projection* details like (name, description, price, feature, benefits, number of installations, reviews...).

Now I wonder If I am allowed to create **Open** command in **Application** *aggregate*. It will not change *aggregate* state, invariants are irrelevant for it. This *command* is only needed because of Statistics *projections*.

Additional problem is that some **Applications** might be visited hundred times each day so it can generate enormous number of *events* to process when *aggregate* is load into memory.

Do You think that creating **Open** *command* in **Application** aggregate in order to emit **Opened** *event* is a good way to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you have to decide if this is just an Access Control thing or real domain functionality... maybe in another Bounded Context then?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is responsibility of Analytics BC, but Opened event might help with Application scoring algorithm which is inside Application aggregate - hard to say at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can the **Open** command be denied by the **Application** aggregate? 
If it cannot, is it really a command?

We issue commands to aggregates in order to validate them, and potentially deny them, if the current state of the aggregate does not allow the command to be executed.

If the **Open** command cannot be denied, and you still are determined to solve the user-tracking with events, you could consider simply issuing an **ApplicationOpened** event, without issuing a command to the aggregate.

Another option could be to track user actions and statistics in a another system entirely, perhaps just adding rows to a database table.

Comment: Yes, Open command can be denied, ie application can not be Opened when is not Published. I already solved that by moving all this statistics/analytics stuff to separate BoundedContext. Thanks anyway for giving different look at the problem.